# Getting error while passing spaced folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

**Code: -**

```
filesDirName="/C/Users/OM\\ SAI\\ RAM/HelloWorldSagar"
echo ${filesDirName}
echo "cd ${filesDirName}"
cd ${filesDirName}
```

***bash output: -***

```
$ ./files.sh
/C/Users/OM\ SAI\ RAM/HelloWorldSagar
cd /C/Users/OM\ SAI\ RAM/HelloWorldSagar
./files.sh: line 4: cd: too many arguments
```

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060083/getting-error-in-while-passing-spaced-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
# No backslash before space needed, as the entire sting is quoted with "
filesDirName="/C/Users/OM SAI RAM/HelloWorldSagar"
# echo allows multiple parameter, so it worked by chance
# You should quote it anyway
echo "${filesDirName}"
echo "cd ${filesDirName}"
# quote the parameter
cd "${filesDirName}"
```

Rule of thumb: If in doubt, quote the variable.

BTW: Indent your code  by 4 spaces, so it is displayed as a code block